# Problem in selecting hypothesis

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

[image]

[image]

This question form edexcel S2 past paper with answer copied from the marking scheme. Here why we put alternative hypothesis as $p>0.5$ without using $p<0.5$ because in question it mention as "no better than". Please help.

Comment: The null hypothesis is formulated in such a way that if it holds, then you can exactly calculate whatever probabilities you need to calculate. Here the alternative hypothesis is $p>0.5$ (the weather is more accurate than coin flipping). The negation of that is $p \leq 0.5$. The worst case scenario in that negation in terms of supporting $p>0.5$ is $p=0.5$.

Comment: @Ian The weather is more accurate than coin flipping??? How? Question says local radio are no better than those achieved by tossing a fair coin.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "the weather forceast is more accurate than coin flipping".

Comment: @Ian I still don't understand? How do you say like that? can you explain plz. If the weather forecast is more accurate than coin flipping then there is no problem to solve right?

Comment: The *alternative hypothesis* is that $p>0.5$, which would mean that the weather forecast is more accurate than coin flipping. The alternative hypothesis is the *alternative* that we suspect to be true if we reject the *null hypothesis*. The null hypothesis in this case is $p=0.5$. This is because it is the case of the negation of the alternative hypothesis (that is, the case of $p \leq 0.5$) which would be the worst case for supporting the alternative hypothesis. We can't take the null hypothesis to actually be $p \leq 0.5$ because you can't calculate anything with just that assumption.

Comment: So there is indeed something to check: you should consider how often in the 30 recorded days the weather was accurate, and compare it to the Binomial(30,0.5) distribution (which is the distribution for the number of heads in 30 fair coin flips).

Comment: If you still don't understand, I would recommend that you gain some understanding by first looking into a problem involving a two-tailed test instead of a one-tailed test. These are easier to intuitively understand, because in this case the null hypothesis is *exactly* the negation of the alternative hypothesis (instead of having to deal with this "worst case scenario" thinking).

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much for your help. Now only I got it. Thanks again.